# Using command prompt to open a website and enter a username and password

Tags: browser, cmd, command, prompt

I am trying to determine if it is possible to write a command for command prompt that would open a website and then enter a username and password on a login prompt. For example, say you are on a network and want to be able to have a browser(i'm using chrome) browse to multiple addresses and then once at the site login with a username and password. Is there a way to tell command prompt to open a site and then tab 3 times and then enter text(like a username) and then tab(to get into password field) and then enter more text and then tell it to "hit enter" to login?

We don't always have access to the exact ips/urls for certain equipment. This is what I have come up with so far but it just will open a range of sites/ips, I can't figure out how to enter username and password automatically.

Example of command i've come up with - for /l %x in (15,1,25) do start http://192.168.1.%x

So this will open 192.168.1.15, 192.168.1.16, 192.168.1.17 ect all the way to 192.168.1.25 in different tabs in the default browser. But I want to have it enter a username and password afterwards if possible.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible in [basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

The following syntax can be used to provide username and password:

[`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) `http://username:password@website.com`

The username is delimited by `:` from the password, and the credentials are delimited by `@` from the host (its domain or IP address).

See [mod_auth_basic](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_auth_basic.html) for configuring such authentication server-side on [apache](/questions/tagged/apache).

Comment: Literally Not Working.

Comment: it won't work if your default browser is [tag:google-chrome], you might consider changing `start` command to `firefox`

Comment: tried chrome, opera, firefox and IE. not working. Btw I'm using my own website

Comment: `user:password@` in a URL might be deprecated. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.1

Comment: This only works if the website uses basic authentication.